# Delayed Onset Muscles Soreness (DOMS) and Muscle Growth

Tags: bodybuilding, physical-therapy

My own understanding of the delayed onset muscles soreness (DOMS) is that the skeleton muscle pain comes from the broken muscle fibres after the workout in the gym. Human body would repair these broken muscle fibres; and therefore, the skeleton muscle would grow bigger and bigger gradually. In other words, DOMS indicates that people did good enough workout in the gym and the targeted skeleton muscle would grow for sure.

On the other hand, I found some people online said that DOMS does not have to mean that the workout is good and the targeted skeleton muscle would be developed.

Is it true? If so, what is the reason behind it? Would anyone please give me some explanations for that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the theories behind muscle hypertrophy was that muscle damage was the main signals that told muscles to grow.  So the idea was that you do a lot of damage to the muscle and you'd get bigger.

We know that this is not really the case because then you wouldn't really have to workout to get bigger muscles.  You could just stab your arm with needles or beat your quad with a club.  Yeah it would hurt, but so do DOMs.  At least with this strategy, you'd cause far more damage to the muscle in a shorter amount of effort. But we know that this doesn't work.

We also know it doesn't work because other athletes who don't train for hypertrophy cause massive amounts of damage to their muscles, but they don't continuously grow in size.  You think of like a marathon runner who runs 40+ miles a week.  They are constantly damaging their leg muscles, but they maintain a pretty thin physique.

The other problem with the theory is that DOMs are variable depending on several factors.  A person who's trained consistently for two years may not feel DOMs anymore at all, but their training is probably way more effective then it was when they first started.  Their body has just adapted to the work load.

Now the prevailing theory is that *at least one of* the main causes of muscle hypertrophy is a mix of [mechanical tension plus metabolic stress](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6950543/). Basically, forcing a muscle to push against a resistance to the point the muscle becomes low in energy.

I think the reason people thought DOMs where an important indicator of a good workout is it's really difficult to separate the two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In other words, DOMs does not mean that the skeleton muscle definitely grow bigger. The basic mechanism is mechanical tension and metabolic stress. Is it correct?

Comment: @Kieran That is the current theory until they come up with a new one, yes.

Comment: I can vouch for the last part of that from experience. I've been training hard and consistently for ~3 years, my best friend had never done any strength training in his life. The other day we went to the gym together and hit chest, obviously using different weights but aiming for a similar RPE. The days after he complained of a lot of sorness in his pecs, but for me, like usual, it was barely noticeable. That being said, I'm terrible for skipping leg day so when I do hit a hard leg day, I still get a LOT of sorness.

Comment: @Deev Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Ethan Thank you for the answer.